# Любой Редактор в WordPress удаляет <script>

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно вставить простой скрипт на страницу, но после сохранения страницы, теги   исчезают, и так на всех редакторах (Elementor, clasic wordpress, Gutenberg). Я сайт унаследовал, и не знаю 
где может быть записана такая функция "фильтрации тегов", подскажите пожалуйста где искать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вставки js кода в редакторе WP есть специальный плагин

> https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/

Либо можно самому создать шорткод - данный код вставить в файл function.php вашей темы WP

> `function myscript_shortcode($atts, $text) {
>      global $post;
>      return get_post_meta($post->ID, $text, true);
>   }
>   add_shortcode('myscript','myscript_shortcode');`

и вызывать его подобным образом:
`[myscript]тут ваш скрипт[/myscript]`

UPD: еще есть очень интересный сайт, где можно найти много информации по вашим и по многим другим вопросам: [ссылка на тот самый сайт](http://google.com)